# lite version setting bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created an app which has two targets, a lite version and a full version.
How do I include different settings bundles in the project?
The two versions always have different app names, such 'aaa' and 'aaa lite'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to settings bundles in different subfolders and assign one to target A and one to target B